# Custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm building an app on visual studio xamarin.ios but the story board opens up with this message "custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected".

I've tried deleting directories named "bin" and "obj" in the project's folder yet the problem persists. Also a log file comes up saying "MonoTouchDesignServerUnified quit unexpectedly".

Here is a screenshot of the log file.

[image: Screenshot of the log file]

Comment: 1. Update your vs to the latest version  . 2. create an empty storyboard to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in current version of Xamarin on how it handle the `UIViewController` define in storyboard. Apparently if the `UIViewController` define in storyboard, it will add as a custom component. Hence, it will try to execute the code in `ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear...` when the storyboard is open.

The solution temporary is set the flag `DesignTimeVisible` to false for those `UIViewController` that is define in storyboard. Xamarin already said that it is fixed and will release in coming version.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class AAAViewController : UIViewController
```

You can refer for more detail in my blog [HERE](https://lowleetak.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/xamarin-ios-storyboard-rendering-problem-with-nullreferenceexception/)