# Having trouble with storyboard file. error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I was recently given an old project and asked to add a camera function to it, however I've never worked with storyboard based apps before. I've found some code that seems like it should work with my project so I just copied a single scene from their storyboard file and tried to paste it into mine. I also added the necessary viewController file and linked its designer code as well. It compiles and runs fine. But when I try to add a segue (just to test, I changed the destination for one segue id to the id of the new viewController) it throws this error:

```
ibtoold[1017:77359] -[IBObjectRecord ibParentItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc65a884b0
```

Also when I try to open the storyboard file in XCode, it starts to load it and seems like everything is there. But near the end, XCode just closes and Visual Studio shows an error saying "Visual Studio can't communicate with XCode".

Then I try to open it in Visual Studio with iOS Designer and all of my pages pull up except for the camera page. And it pops up a warning that says "custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected". I choose to view the log file and there are a few "ERROR: Could not find" lines near the bottom of the file (I have no clue what I'm looking at here).

```
[2017-12-01 10:13:31.5] INFO: Reloading: Server rendering completed in 5781ms
com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.186 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.1] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.returnKeyType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.192 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.1] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.autocorrectionType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.192 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.1] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.spellCheckingType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.193 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.1] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.keyboardType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.212 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.secureTextEntry

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.232 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.returnKeyType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.243 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.autocorrectionType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.261 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.spellCheckingType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.293 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.keyboardType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.845 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.8] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.textInputTraits

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:32.895 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:32.8] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.textInputTraits

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.082 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.0] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.textInputTraits

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.272 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.keyboardType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.294 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.2] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.spellCheckingType
2017-12-01 10:13:33.301 MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] 
[2017-12-01 10:13:33.3] ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextField.autocorrectionType

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.310 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.3] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedViewController.storyboardIdentifier

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.317 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.3] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.textInputTraits

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.360 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.3] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.textInputTraits

com.xamarin.MTHosting.3f6fb37b1.stderr: 2017-12-01 10:13:33.395 
MonoTouchDesignServerUnified[2215:229549] [2017-12-01 10:13:33.3] 
ERROR: Could not find MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedTextView.accessibility
```

I guess I'm just not really sure how to go about editing this Storyboard file other than simply copy-pasting code into its Source Code. And when I do, it's not turning out well. Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

I'd also be glad to post some code, but doing the whole storyboard file is just WAY too much.

EDIT: By the way, all of these XCode errors and iOS Designer erros persist even without the camera page added in if that's any help at all.

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369386/custom-components-are-not-being-rendered-because-problems-were-detected

Comment: tried it and it's still saying that custom components are not being rendered... I'm gonna post the errors from that log file in the post.